# Cannot find python libraries for CMake in Opencv3.0.0

Tags: python-2.7, cmake, cmake-gui, opencv3.0

Trying to build Opencv3.0.0 (dev), cmake finds the binary and python 2 locations but isn't able to include python libraries.

I use cmake-gui for makefile generation. While configuring cmake, it gives this piece of info along with other various :

> --
>
> --   Python 2:
>
> --     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
>
> --     Libraries:                   NO
>
> --     numpy:                       /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.8.2)
>
> --     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
>
> --
>
> --   Python 3:
>
> --     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3.4 (ver 3.4)

I have cross checked and the input for python2 I provide are all correct (included as attachment):
[image]
(Please take a look at the image before reading further)

So, now I am wondering whether this is architecture problem or version problem (compatibility with different versions of opencv, python, cmake)

**Versions I am currently using are :**
opencv : 3.0.0-dev

python2 : 2.7.6

python3 : 3.4.0

cmake : 2.8.12.2

System : ubuntu 14.04 (amd architecture, 64 bit)

Linux Kernel version : Linux version 3.13.0-27-generic (buildd@akateko) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #50-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 15 18:06:16 UTC 2014

I am, at this point stuck as to what to do . Can someone nudge me in right direction please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be too late for an answer. I encounter the exactly same error as yours. The reason is that the cmake is out-of-date. You can upgrade your cmake following https://askubuntu.com/questions/610291/how-to-install-cmake-3-2-on-ubuntu-14-04. After that everything works just fine.